# Rails Resources new and edit routes redirecting to root page instead of their respective routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Basically, I'm trying to update the layout of my *portfolio/new* form but whenever I type in **'localhost:3000/portfolios/new'** I get redirected to my home page. Same with **'localhost:3000/portfolios/(:id)/edit'**

My routes are below:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #Devise Routes
  devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', sign_up: 'register' }
  #homepages routes
  get 'about-me', to: 'pages#about'
  get 'contact', to: 'pages#contact'
  # blog
  resources :blogs do
    member do
      get :toggle_status
    end
  end
  #portfolio
  resources :portfolios, except: [:show]
  get 'portfolio/:id', to: 'portfolios#show', as: 'portfolio_show'
  get 'react-items', to: 'portfolios#react'
  # setting root path --> ex: localhost:3000/
  root to: 'pages#home'
end
```

Here is my controller:

```
 class PortfoliosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_portfolio_item, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]
  layout "portfolio"
  access all: [:show, :index, :react], user: {except: [:destroy, :new, :create, :update, :edit]}, site_admin: :all
  
  def index
    @portfolio_items = Portfolio.all
  end

  # custom scope
  def react
    @react_portfolio_items = Portfolio.react
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    # new portfolio item is initialized.
    @portfolio_item = Portfolio.new
    3.times { @portfolio_item.technologies.build }
  end 

  def create
    @portfolio_item = Portfolio.new(portfolio_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @portfolio_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to portfolios_path, notice: 'Portfolio Item was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @portfolio_item.update(portfolio_params)
        format.html { redirect_to portfolios_path, notice: 'Portfolio Item was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit}
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    # destroy the record
    @portfolio_item.destroy

    # redirect
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to portfolios_url, notice: 'Record was removed.' }
    end
  end

  private

  def portfolio_params
    params.require(:portfolio).permit(:title, 
                                      :subtitle, 
                                      :body, 
                                      technologies_attributes: [:name]
                                    )
  end

  def set_portfolio_item
    @portfolio_item = Portfolio.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

So overall I'm not sure why it's doing that. When I do **rails routes** I can see the correct paths but when I input them in the browser, they do not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My bet is a) either the user isn't logged in, or b) the access filter on the controller is set up incorrectly. `access all: [:show, :index, :react], user: {except: [:destroy, :new, :create, :update, :edit]}, site_admin: :all`.

Comment: You were right! I was using a test user that did not have admin privileges. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you had reverted access to **create/update/edit/destroy**.

Remove `except` condition from `access_all` for user `create/update/edit/destroy`

when `user` trying to opening a page which doesn't has permission to `view`, it will be `redirect_to` its `root_path` by default.